# End-of-Transmission character as an IFS

Tags: sh

I have a Bourne shell script which uses End-of-Transmission character as an IFS:

```
ASCII_EOT=`echo -e '\004'`
while IFS="$ASCII_EOT" read DEST PASSWORD; do
    ...
done
```

How does the EOT behave as an IFS? Or what kind of input might the `read` expect?

Comment: Are you sure it is a Bourne shell script?  The `echo -e` implies you are either using `bash` or the external GNU `echo` binary, in which case it's probably safe to assume you can use `bash` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an ASCII character just like `,`; it just isn't printable.

```
$ printf 'foo\004bar' > tmp.txt
$ hexdump -C tmp.txt
00000000  66 6f 6f 04 62 61 72 0a                           |foo.bar.|
00000008
$ IFS=$(printf '\004') read f1 f2 < tmp.txt
$ echo "$f1"
foo
$ echo "$f2"
bar
```